# warning: value computed is not used

Tags: c++, warnings, gcc-warning

Why do I get this warning message "warning: value computed is not used" at line "BIO_flush(b64);" and how can I get rid of it?

```
unsigned char *my_base64(unsigned char *input, int length)
{
    BIO *bmem, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *bptr;

    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
    BIO_write(b64, input, length);
    BIO_flush(b64);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);

    unsigned char *buff = (unsigned char *)malloc(bptr->length+1);
    memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length-1);
    buff[bptr->length-1] = 0;

    BIO_free_all(b64);

    return buff;
}
```

Comment: `BIO_flush()` is probably declared to return something, but you're not storing the result anywhere or using in an expression.

Comment: BIO_flush() will be declared as a macro that computes a value. Because the result is not assigned to a variable you will get this warning. I think that if BIO_flush was a real function this warning would not occur. I think to avoid the warning under -Wall you need to assign to a temporary

Comment: `BIO_flush` could also be a macro expanding to an expression with a comma operator, where the left hand side of the comma operator has no side effect. Without seeing the definition of `BIO_flush` all that is just bling guessing, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The common way to deal with these errors is to *"explicitly cast the return value away"*:

```
(void) BIO_flush(b64);
```

Alternatively you can choose to turn off this warning alltogether by adding the `-Wno-unused-value` flag.

---

The above obviously assumes you are not interested in the return value. If you are unsure, look in the documentation exactly what it returns and decide whether you want to store/use this or not.

Comment: Since you're writing to a memory buffer `BIO_s_mem()`, I expect `BIO_flush` will only fail on out-of-memory. So "you are not interested in the return value" is more-or-less equivalent to "there's nothing reasonable for your function to do if you run out of memory". Since the code in the question doesn't check the return value of `malloc` either, that's currently true. If not necessarily wise.